# Add custom rule to git flow

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I'd like to add some custom rules to my git flow enforce some important aspects of my workflow.

For example:

- each time a feature branch is merged into develop the changelog must be modified

I'm using both command line git and [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), but any kind of solution could be available.

Comment: There may be a git hook suitable for your needs https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how SourceTree has integrated git-flow, but if you use CLI you can use [git-flow AVH](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh) which supports hooks and filters. One of the hooks is feature-finish, which you can use to update changelogs, version numbers etc etc. Whatever you can do programmatically you can do in the hooks.